# What are the exact requirements for MyType to allow std::atomic<MyType>?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdatomic

I would like to communicate some Informations between threads.
Atomics sound like the thing to use.
I had a look at [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). And found that a simple struct like

```
struct MyType{
  int val_a,val_b;
  float vals_c[5];
};
```

should fullfill the assert:

```
static_assert( 
  std::is_trivially_copyable<MyType>::value &&
  std::is_copy_constructible<MyType>::value &&
  std::is_move_constructible<MyType>::value &&
  std::is_copy_assignable<MyType>::value &&
  std::is_move_assignable<MyType>::value, 
  "MyType is not suitable for std::atomic");
```

)

But a simple program as

```
//... MyType and static_assert

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
   MyType a;
   std::atomic<MyType> b;
   b = a;
   a = b;
   return 0;
}
```

fails to compile with:

```
undefined reference to `__atomic_store'
undefined reference to `__atomic_load'
```

I am using gcc version 5.4 on a 64-bit ubuntu 16.04.

Flags used are: `-pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC`

Is it that this is a total wrong use of `std::atomic`? What are the requirements to MyType? Or is just something missing from this setup?

Comment: Looks like this works from gcc version 7 onwards. Likely just a compiler bug that was fixed in version 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As always, [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) is your friend:

> The primary `std::atomic` template may be instantiated with any *TriviallyCopyable* type T satisfying both *CopyConstructible* and *CopyAssignable*. The program is ill-formed if any of following values is `false`:
>
> `std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value`
>   `std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value`
>   `std::is_move_constructible<T>::value`
>   `std::is_copy_assignable<T>::value`
>   `std::is_move_assignable<T>::value`

So, your assert is good.

Later it says:

> On gcc and clang, some of the functionality described here requires linking against `-latomic`.

So, if the program still fails to build, [you may need to link against `libatomic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65756).

If it *still* doesn't work, you probably have a compiler bug.

Comment: Does this answer implies that the code should work?

Comment: @generic_opto_guy The code looks fine to me. Did you try linking against `libatomic` as I suggested?

Comment: @generic_opto_guy It does for me. [Before](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9265d35ce3af6c25) / [After](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f26646d5bcb4e7c)

Comment: I checked on GCC 5.4 too; same results ([After](https://godbolt.org/z/JkBp48))

Comment: @generic_opto_guy Don't forget that libraries have to be listed _after_ the TU that requires them, so put `-latomic` at the end of the command, not the beginning

Comment: Oh, you found my error. Now it works with the flag.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy: if your code needs `-latomic` it usually means that you used an `atomic<T>` that wasn't `is_lock_free`.  e.g. larger than 8 bytes on x86-64.  (Or with older gcc and `-mxc16`, it treats 16-byte structs as lock-free as well, but it has to use `lock cmpxchg16b` even for pure loads and store so read don't scale with multiple threads.)

Comment: @PeterCordes `sizeof(MyType) > 8` clearly holds. If I reduce the size of `MyType` I indeed do not need `-latomic`.